# Electron Squirrel createShortcut not working with options

Tags: node.js, electron, squirrel.windows

I'm trying to pass `--createShortcut -l="StartMenu"` to squirrel's `Update.exe` but it doesn't seem to work. Once I remove the `-l` option it succeeds. I am using electron for the main app and node's `spawnSync` to create it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the quotation. Even though the documentation says that we should use the quotation calling it via spawnSync started working once I got rid of the quotes.